# Concatinate 2 or more dataframes from dataframe list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to concatinate 2 or more dataframes from list which contains some number of data frames.

For example:

**DataFrameList = [ A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C]** where A, B, C are names of particular data frame. Data frames with same names have same number of rows, but not the columns and also they have same id colmn... So idea is to concatinate all data frames with same names and that at the end I get new list of data frames which would be like this (based on upper list) **DataFramelist2 = [A, B, C]**

If anyone has some idea please share it :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

You can sort th list by number of rows and then use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby


DataFrameList = sorted(DataFrameList, key=lambda x: x.shape[0])

DF = []

for _, group in groupby(DataFrameList, key=lambda x: x.shape[0]):
    DF += [pd.concat(group)]
```